# Codepipeline Error using Environment Variables with Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, environment-variables, aws-codepipeline

So I am running into an error with AWS Codepipeline:

> Error: Error creating CodePipeline: ValidationException:
> ActionConfiguration Map value must satisfy constraint: [Member must
> have length less than or equal to 1000, Member must have a length
> greater than or equal to 1]

Google it tells me that I have too many Pipeline Environment variables.  It tells me I have a character limit of 1000 characters.  I am not sure what that means, does it mean my values for my Environment variables can not exceed 100 characters or does it mean that the json that makes up the environment variables can't exceed 1000 characters?

Appreciate the help here.

Terraform code as requested:

```
resource "aws_codepipeline" "cp_plan_pipeline" {
  name       = "${local.cp_name}-cp"
  role_arn   = aws_iam_role.cp_service_role.arn

  artifact_store {
    type     = var.cp_artifact_type
    location = module.S3.bucket_name
  }

  stage {
    name = "Initialize"

    action {
      run_order           = 1  
      name                = "Source"
      category            = "Source"
      owner               = "AWS"
      provider            = "CodeCommit"
      version             = "1"
      input_artifacts     = [] 
      output_artifacts    = ["CodeWorkspace"]

      configuration = {
        RepositoryName        = var.cp_repo_name
        BranchName            = var.cp_branch_name
        PollForSourceChanges  = var.cp_poll_sources
        OutputArtifactFormat  = var.cp_ouput_format
      }
    }
  }

  stage {
    name = "Build"

    action {
      run_order           = 1
      name                = "Combine_Binaries"
      category            = "Build"
      owner               = "AWS"
      provider            = "CodeBuild"
      version             = "1"
      namespace           = "BINARYVARIABLE"
      input_artifacts     = ["CodeWorkspace"]
      output_artifacts    = ["CodeSource"]

      configuration = {
        ProjectName          = var.cp_binary_project_name
        EnvironmentVariables = jsonencode([
          {
            name  = "PIPELINE_EXECUTION_ID"
            type  = "PLAINTEXT"
            value = "#{codepipeline.PipelineExecutionId}"
          },
          {
            name  = "PL_BUCKET_KEY"
            type  = "PLAINTEXT"
            value = "global/state/${var.bucketlocation}/"
          },
          {
            name  = "PL_DYNAMODB_TABLE_NAME"
            type  = "PLAINTEXT"
            value = "${var.project}-${var.env}-${var.tenant}-db-${var.bucketlocation}"
          },
          {
            name  = "PL_JQ_VERSION"
            type  = "PLAINTEXT"
            value = var.JQ_VER
          },
          {
            name  = "PL_PY_VERSION"
            type  = "PLAINTEXT"
            value = var.PY_VER
          },
          {
            name  = "PL_GO_VERSION"
            type  = "PLAINTEXT"
            value = var.TF_VER
          },                                                
          {
            name  = "PL_TF_VERSION"
            type  = "PLAINTEXT"
            value = var.TF_VER
          },
          {
            name  = "PL_GROUP_NAME"
            type  = "PLAINTEXT"
            value = var.group_name
          },
          {
            name  = "PL_GROUP_EMAIL"
            type  = "PLAINTEXT"
            value = var.group_email
          },
          {
            name  = "PL_PROJECT"
            type  = "PLAINTEXT"
            value = var.project
          },
          {
            name  = "PL_TENANT"
            type  = "PLAINTEXT"
            value = var.tenant
          },
          {
            name  = "PL_APPENV"
            type  = "PLAINTEXT"  
            value = ""
          },
          {
            name  = "PL_AWSACCOUNTNAME"
            type  = "PLAINTEXT"
            value = ""
          },
          {
            name  = "PL_AWSACCOUNTNUMB"
            type  = "PLAINTEXT"
            value = ""
          },
          {
            name  = "PL_PERMISSION_SETS_DIR"
            type  = "PLAINTEXT"  
            value = ""
          },
        ])
      }
    }
  }

  stage {
    name = "Code_Validation"

    action {
      run_order         = 1           
      name              = "Build_Lint_Py"
      category          = "Build"
      owner             = "AWS"
      provider          = "CodeBuild"
      version           = "1"
      input_artifacts   = ["CodeSource"]
      output_artifacts  = ["pyReport"]

      configuration = {
        ProjectName          = var.cp_lintpy_project_name
        EnvironmentVariables = jsonencode([
          {
            name  = "PIPELINE_EXECUTION_ID"
            type  = "PLAINTEXT"
            value = "#{codepipeline.PipelineExecutionId}"
          },
          {
            name  = "PL_PY_VERSION"
            type  = "PLAINTEXT"
            value = "#{BINARYVARIABLE.PL_PY_VERSION}"
          },
          {
            name  = "PL_PERMISSION_SETS_DIR"
            type  = "PLAINTEXT"  
            value = "#{BINARYVARIABLE.PL_PERMISSION_SETS_DIR}"
          },
        ])
      }
    }

    action {
      run_order         = 1           
      name              = "Build_TF_Plan"
      category          = "Build"
      owner             = "AWS"
      provider          = "CodeBuild"
      version           = "1"
      input_artifacts   = ["CodeSource"]
      output_artifacts  = ["buildPlan"]
        
      configuration = {
        ProjectName          = var.cp_build_tf_validate
        #PrimarySource        = "CodeSource"
        EnvironmentVariables = jsonencode([
          {
            name  = "PIPELINE_EXECUTION_ID"
            type  = "PLAINTEXT"
            value = "#{codepipeline.PipelineExecutionId}"
          },
          {
            name  = "PL_APP_NAME"
            type  = "PLAINTEXT"
            value = var.bucketlocation
          },
          {
            name  = "PL_BUCKET_KEY"
            type  = "PLAINTEXT"
            value = "#{BINARYVARIABLE.PL_BUCKET_KEY}"
          },
          {
            name  = "PL_DYNAMODB_TABLE_NAME"
            type  = "PLAINTEXT"
            value = "#{BINARYVARIABLE.PL_DYNAMODB_TABLE_NAME}"
          },
          {
            name  = "PL_JQ_VERSION"
            type  = "PLAINTEXT"
            value = "#{BINARYVARIABLE.PL_JQ_VERSION}"
          },
          {
            name  = "PL_PY_VERSION"
            type  = "PLAINTEXT"
            value = "#{BINARYVARIABLE.PL_PY_VERSION}"
          },
          {
            name  = "PL_TF_VERSION"
            type  = "PLAINTEXT"
            value = "#{BINARYVARIABLE.PL_TF_VERSION}"
          },
          {
            name  = "PL_GROUP_NAME"
            type  = "PLAINTEXT"
            value = "#{BINARYVARIABLE.PL_GROUP_NAME}"
          },
          {
            name  = "PL_GROUP_EMAIL"
            type  = "PLAINTEXT"
            value = "#{BINARYVARIABLE.PL_GROUP_EMAIL}"
          },
          {
            name  = "PL_PROJECT"
            type  = "PLAINTEXT"
            value = "#{BINARYVARIABLE.PL_PROJECT}"
          },
          {
            name  = "PL_TENANT"
            type  = "PLAINTEXT"
            value = "#{BINARYVARIABLE.PL_TENANT}"
          },
          {
            name  = "PL_APPENV"
            type  = "PLAINTEXT"  
            value = "#{BINARYVARIABLE.PL_APPENV}"
          },
          {
            name  = "PL_AWSACCOUNTNUMB"
            type  = "PLAINTEXT"
            value = "#{BINARYVARIABLE.PL_AWSACCOUNTNUMB}"
          },
          {
            name  = "PL_PERMISSION_SETS_DIR"
            type  = "PLAINTEXT"  
            value = "#{BINARYVARIABLE.PL_PERMISSION_SETS_DIR}"
          },
        ])
      }
    }

    action {
      run_order         = 1           
      name              = "Build_Lint_TF"
      category          = "Build"
      owner             = "AWS"
      provider          = "CodeBuild"
      version           = "1"
      input_artifacts   = ["CodeSource"]
      output_artifacts  = ["tfReport"]

      configuration = {
        ProjectName          = var.cp_linttf_project_name
        #PrimarySource        = "CodeSource"
        EnvironmentVariables = jsonencode([
          {
            name  = "PIPELINE_EXECUTION_ID"
            type  = "PLAINTEXT"
            value = "#{codepipeline.PipelineExecutionId}"
          },
          {
            name  = "PL_BUCKET_KEY"
            type  = "PLAINTEXT"
            value = "#{BINARYVARIABLE.PL_BUCKET_KEY}"
          },
          {
            name  = "PL_DYNAMODB_TABLE_NAME"
            type  = "PLAINTEXT"
            value = "#{BINARYVARIABLE.PL_DYNAMODB_TABLE_NAME}"
          },
          {
            name  = "PL_TF_VERSION"
            type  = "PLAINTEXT"
            value = var.TF_VER
          },
          {
            name  = "PL_TF_LINT_VERSION"
            type  = "PLAINTEXT"
            value = "#{BINARYVARIABLE.PL_TF_LINT_VERSION}"
          },
          {
            name  = "PL_PERMISSION_SETS_DIR"
            type  = "PLAINTEXT"  
            value = "#{BINARYVARIABLE.PL_PERMISSION_SETS_DIR}"
          },
        ])
      }
    }
  }

  stage {
    name = "Test"

    action {
      run_order         = 1        
      name              = "Static_Analysis_Py"
      category          = "Test"
      owner             = "AWS"
      provider          = "CodeBuild"
      version           = "1"
      input_artifacts   = ["CodeSource"]
      output_artifacts  = ["pySecReport"]

      configuration = {
        ProjectName          = var.cp_test_static_py
        PrimarySource        = "CodeSource"
        EnvironmentVariables = jsonencode([
          {
            name  = "PIPELINE_EXECUTION_ID"
            type  = "PLAINTEXT"
            value = "#{codepipeline.PipelineExecutionId}"
          },
          {
            name  = "PL_JQ_VERSION"
            type  = "PLAINTEXT"
            value = "#{BINARYVARIABLE.PL_JQ_VERSION}"
          },
          {
            name  = "PL_PY_VERSION"
            type  = "PLAINTEXT"
            value = "#{BINARYVARIABLE.PL_PY_VERSION}"
          },
          {
            name  = "PL_PERMISSION_SETS_DIR"
            type  = "PLAINTEXT"  
            value = "#{BINARYVARIABLE.PL_PERMISSION_SETS_DIR}"
          },
        ])
      }
    }

    action {
      run_order         = 1        
      name              = "Static_Analysis_TFSec"
      category          = "Test"
      owner             = "AWS"
      provider          = "CodeBuild"
      version           = "1"
      namespace         = "TESTVARIABLE"
      input_artifacts   = ["CodeSource"]
      output_artifacts  = ["tfSecReport"]

      configuration = {
        ProjectName          = var.cp_test_static_tf
        #PrimarySource        = "CodeSource"
        EnvironmentVariables = jsonencode([
          {
            name  = "PIPELINE_EXECUTION_ID"
            type  = "PLAINTEXT"
            value = "#{codepipeline.PipelineExecutionId}"
          },
          {
            name  = "PL_JQ_VERSION"
            type  = "PLAINTEXT"  
            value = "#{BINARYVARIABLE.PL_JQ_VERSION}"
          },
          {
            name  = "PL_TFSEC_VERSION"
            type  = "PLAINTEXT"
            value = "#{BINARYVARIABLE.PL_TFSEC_VERSION}"
          },
          {
            name  = "PL_PERMISSION_SETS_DIR"
            type  = "PLAINTEXT"  
            value = "#{BINARYVARIABLE.PL_PERMISSION_SETS_DIR}"
          },
          #{
          #  name  = "PL_ARTIFACTBUCKET"
          #  type  = "PLAINTEXT"  
          #  value = "${var.project}-${var.env}-${var.tenant}-${var.cp_name}-cp-artifacts"
          #},  
          #{
          #  name  = "PL_TFSECAPPROVALLINK"
          #  type  = "PLAINTEXT"  
          #  value = ""
          #},
        ])
      }
    }
  }

  stage {
    name = "Manual_Approval_Action"

    action {
      run_order           = 1
      name                = "Manual_Review_Action-${var.project}-${var.env}-${var.tenant}-${var.cp_name}"
      category            = "Approval"
      owner               = "AWS"
      provider            = "Manual"
      version             = "1"
      input_artifacts     = []
      output_artifacts    = []

      configuration  = {
        NotificationArn       = module.sns_cp.op_sns_topic_arn
        CustomData            = "Please review the static code analysis and the repoistory before code is deployed."
      }
    }
  }

  stage {
    name = "Deploy"

    action {
      run_order           = 1
      name                = "Terraform-Apply"
      category            = "Build"
      owner               = "AWS"
      provider            = "CodeBuild"
      input_artifacts     = ["CodeSource","buildPlan"]
      output_artifacts    = []
      version             = "1"

      configuration = {
        ProjectName          = var.cp_apply_project_name
        PrimarySource        = "CodeSource"
        EnvironmentVariables = jsonencode([
          {
            name  = "PIPELINE_EXECUTION_ID"
            value = "#{codepipeline.PipelineExecutionId}"
            type  = "PLAINTEXT"
          },
          {
            name  = "PL_PERMISSION_SETS_DIR"
            type  = "PLAINTEXT"  
            value = "#{BINARYVARIABLE.PL_PERMISSION_SETS_DIR}"
          },    
          {
            name  = "PL_BUCKET_KEY"
            type  = "PLAINTEXT"
            value = "#{BINARYVARIABLE.PL_BUCKET_KEY}"
          },
          {
            name  = "PL_DYNAMODB_TABLE_NAME"
            type  = "PLAINTEXT"
            value = "#{BINARYVARIABLE.PL_DYNAMODB_TABLE_NAME}"
          },
          {
            name  = "PL_TF_VERSION"
            type  = "PLAINTEXT"
            value = "#{BINARYVARIABLE.PL_TF_VERSION}"
          },
          {
            name  = "PL_GROUP_NAME"
            type  = "PLAINTEXT"
            value = "#{BINARYVARIABLE.PL_GROUP_NAME}"
          },
          {
            name  = "PL_GROUP_EMAIL"
            type  = "PLAINTEXT"
            value = "#{BINARYVARIABLE.PL_GROUP_EMAIL}"
          },
          {
            name  = "PL_PROJECT"
            type  = "PLAINTEXT"
            value = "#{BINARYVARIABLE.PL_PROJECT}"
          },
          {
            name  = "PL_TENANT"
            type  = "PLAINTEXT"
            value = "#{BINARYVARIABLE.PL_TENANT}"
          },
          {
            name  = "PL_APPENV"
            type  = "PLAINTEXT"  
            value = "#{BINARYVARIABLE.PL_APPENV}"
          },
        ])
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Want is your terraform code?

Comment: updated post with code.

Comment: I was able to fix the first stage, and it came down to 11 variables.  Still not sure how that is tied to 1000 characters

Answer (score 2):

Okay, after days of looking into this my colleague, who gets all the credit figured out what the 1000 character limit is.  So keep in mind this is 1000 characters per stage. So without confirmation from Hashicorp, what we came up with is the following:

If you want to open the state file in a text editor, make sure you are viewing the file and not modifying it.  Inside the state file search f,or "EnvironmentVariables"  You will find a JSON syntax, the example shown below of the output.

```
"EnvironmentVariables": "[{\"name\":\"PIPELINE_EXECUTION_ID\",\"type\":\"PLAINTEXT\",\"value\":\"#{codepipeline.PipelineExecutionId}\"},{\"name\":\"PL_APP_NAME\",\"type\":\"PLAINTEXT\",\"value\":\"deploy_pl\"},{\"name\":\"PL_BUCKET_KEY\",\"type\":\"PLAINTEXT\",\"value\":\"#{BIN.PL_BUCKET_KEY}\"},{\"name\":\"PL_DYNAMODB_TABLE_NAME\",\"type\":\"PLAINTEXT\",\"value\":\"#{BIN.PL_DYNAMODB_TABLE_NAME}\"},{\"name\":\"PL_GROUP_NAME\",\"type\":\"PLAINTEXT\",\"value\":\"#{BIN.PL_GROUP_NAME}\"},{\"name\":\"PL_GROUP_EMAIL\",\"type\":\"PLAINTEXT\",\"value\":\"#{BIN.PL_GROUP_EMAIL}\"},{\"name\":\"PL_PROJECT\",\"type\":\"PLAINTEXT\",\"value\":\"#{BIN.PL_PROJECT}\"},{\"name\":\"PL_TENANT\",\"type\":\"PLAINTEXT\",\"value\":\"#{BIN.PL_TENANT}\"},{\"name\":\"PL_APPENV\",\"type\":\"PLAINTEXT\",\"value\":\"#{BIN.PL_APPENV}\"},{\"name\":\"PL_ACCT_NUMB\",\"type\":\"PLAINTEXT\",\"value\":\"#{BIN.PL_ACCT_NUMB}\"},{\"name\":\"PL_PERMISSION_SETS_DIR\",\"type\":\"PLAINTEXT\",\"value\":\"#{BIN.PL_PERMISSION_SETS_DIR}\"},{\"name\":\"PL_IS_MGMT_ACCT\",\"type\":\"PLAINTEXT\",\"value\":\"#{BIN.PL_IS_MGMT_ACCT}\"}]",
```

If you remove "EnvironmentVariables": and the " \ " that gives you a count of the characters within the environment variable section.  It has allowed me to rename and refactor my variables accurately.

So advise going forward:

1. keep namespaces to four or fewer characters
2. keep variables short to save space
3. only use variables in the stage where appropriate